# How to delete file when user cancel upload form?

Tags: jquery, upload, uploadify, delete-file

I have a page allows users to upload some video and document use http://www.uploadify.com/, is there any way to do that: when users quit upload form (refresh, close tab, browser, or click another url), its automatic delete the file that user have just uploaded. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done manually. Once the file is uploaded on the server, you will know the file name. Now you could make an ajax call on the required `Event` when it is fired, which will delete the file using php's `unlink()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the total size of uploaded file. By pasting this in `jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js` and delete it on the cancel button click

```js
    if (jQuery) {
(function (a) {
    a.extend(a.fn, { uploadify: function (b) {
        a(this).each(function () {
            var total = "0";
            var f = a.extend({ id: a(this).attr("id"), uploader: "uploadify.swf", script: "uploadify.php", expressInstall: null, folder: "", height: 30, width: 120, cancelImg: "cancel.png", wmode: "opaque", scriptAccess: "sameDomain", fileDataName: "Filedata", method: "POST", queueSizeLimit: 999, simUploadLimit: 999, queueID: false, displayData: "percentage", removeCompleted: false, onInit: function () { }, onSelect: function () { }, onSelectOnce: function () { }, onQueueFull: function () { }, onCheck: function () { }, onCancel: function () { }, onClearQueue: function () { }, onError: function () { }, onProgress: function () { }, onComplete: function () { }, onAllComplete: function () { } }, b); a(this).data("settings", f); var e = location.pathname; e = e.split("/"); e.pop(); e = e.join("/") + "/"; var g = {}; g.uploadifyID = f.id; g.pagepath = e; if (f.buttonImg) { g.buttonImg = escape(f.buttonImg) } if (f.buttonText) { g.buttonText = escape(f.buttonText) } if (f.rollover) { g.rollover = true } g.script = f.script; g.folder = escape(f.folder); if (f.scriptData) { var h = ""; for (var d in f.scriptData) { h += "&" + d + "=" + f.scriptData[d] } g.scriptData = escape(h.substr(1)) } g.width = f.width; g.height = f.height; g.wmode = f.wmode; g.method = f.method; g.queueSizeLimit = f.queueSizeLimit; g.simUploadLimit = f.simUploadLimit; if (f.hideButton) { g.hideButton = true } if (f.fileDesc) { g.fileDesc = f.fileDesc } if (f.fileExt) { g.fileExt = f.fileExt } if (f.multi) { g.multi = true } if (f.auto) { g.auto = true } if (f.sizeLimit) { g.sizeLimit = f.sizeLimit } if (f.checkScript) { g.checkScript = f.checkScript } if (f.fileDataName) { g.fileDataName = f.fileDataName } if (f.queueID) { g.queueID = f.queueID } if (f.onInit() !== false) { a(this).css("display", "none"); a(this).after('<div id="' + a(this).attr("id") + 'Uploader"></div>'); swfobject.embedSWF(f.uploader, f.id + "Uploader", f.width, f.height, "9.0.24", f.expressInstall, g, { quality: "high", wmode: f.wmode, allowScriptAccess: f.scriptAccess }, {}, function (i) { if (typeof (f.onSWFReady) == "function" && i.success) { f.onSWFReady() } }); if (f.queueID == false) { a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + "Uploader").after('<div id="' + a(this).attr("id") + 'Queue" class="uploadifyQueue"></div>') } else { a("#" + f.queueID).addClass("uploadifyQueue") } } if (typeof (f.onOpen) == "function") { a(this).bind("uploadifyOpen", f.onOpen) } a(this).bind("uploadifySelect", { action: f.onSelect, queueID: f.queueID },
             function (k, i, j) {
                 if (k.data.action(k, i, j) !== false) {
                     var l = Math.round(j.size / 1024 * 100) * 0.01; var m = "KB"; /*if (l > 1000) { l = Math.round(l * 0.001 * 100) * 0.01; m = "MB" }*/
                     var n = l.toString().split("."); if (n.length > 1) { l = n[0] + "." + n[1].substr(0, 2) } else { l = n[0] } if (j.name.length > 100) { fileName = j.name.substr(0, 100) + "..." } else { fileName = j.name } queue = "#" + a(this).attr("id") + "Queue"; if (k.data.queueID) { queue = "#" + k.data.queueID }
                     total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(l);
                     if (total <= 4000) {
                         a(queue).append('<div id="' + a(this).attr("id") + i + '" class="uploadifyQueueItem" ><div class="cancel"><a href="javascript:jQuery(\'#' + a(this).attr("id") + "').uploadifyCancel('" + i + '\')"><img src="' + f.cancelImg + '" border="0" style="width:18px;height:18px;" /></a></div><span class="fileName">' + fileName + '</span><span class="percentage"></span><div class="uploadifyProgress"><div id="' + a(this).attr("id") + i + 'ProgressBar" class="uploadifyProgressBar"><!--Progress Bar--></div></div></div>')
                     }
                     else {
                         total = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(l);
                         alert("Total attachment size can not exceed 4Mb.");
                         return;
                     }
                 }
             }); a(this).bind("uploadifySelectOnce", { action: f.onSelectOnce }, function (i, j) { i.data.action(i, j); if (f.auto) { if (f.checkScript) { a(this).uploadifyUpload(null, false) } else { a(this).uploadifyUpload(null, true) } } }); a(this).bind("uploadifyQueueFull", { action: f.onQueueFull }, function (i, j) { if (i.data.action(i, j) !== false) { alert("The queue is full.  The max size is " + j + ".") } }); a(this).bind("uploadifyCheckExist", { action: f.onCheck }, function (n, m, l, k, p) { var j = new Object(); j = l; j.folder = (k.substr(0, 1) == "/") ? k : e + k; if (p) { for (var i in l) { var o = i } } a.post(m, j, function (s) { for (var q in s) { if (n.data.action(n, s, q) !== false) { var r = confirm("Do you want to replace the file " + s[q] + "?"); if (!r) { document.getElementById(a(n.target).attr("id") + "Uploader").cancelFileUpload(q, true, true) } } } if (p) { document.getElementById(a(n.target).attr("id") + "Uploader").startFileUpload(o, true) } else { document.getElementById(a(n.target).attr("id") + "Uploader").startFileUpload(null, true) } }, "json") });
            a(this).bind("uploadifyCancel", { action: f.onCancel }, function (n, j, m, o, i, l) {
                if (n.data.action(n, j, m, o, l) !== false) {
                    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                        url: "../CommonService.asmx/DeleteFileAttachment",
                        data: "{FileNameTOBeDeleted: '" + (a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + j)[0].innerText) + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json", success: function (data) {
                            if (data.d != 0) {
                                // alert("Deleted Successfully");
                                total = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(data.d);
                                if (total < 0) { total = 0; }
                            }
                            else if (data.d == 0) {
                                // if not deleted.
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    if (i) { var k = (l == true) ? 0 : 250; a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + j).fadeOut(k, function () { a(this).remove() }) }
                }
            }); a(this).bind("uploadifyClearQueue", { action: f.onClearQueue }, function (k, j) { var i = (f.queueID) ? f.queueID : a(this).attr("id") + "Queue"; if (j) { a("#" + i).find(".uploadifyQueueItem").remove() } if (k.data.action(k, j) !== false) { a("#" + i).find(".uploadifyQueueItem").each(function () { var l = a(".uploadifyQueueItem").index(this); a(this).delay(l * 100).fadeOut(250, function () { a(this).remove() }) }) } }); var c = []; a(this).bind("uploadifyError", { action: f.onError }, function (m, i, l, k) { if (m.data.action(m, i, l, k) !== false) { var j = new Array(i, l, k); c.push(j); a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + i).find(".percentage").text(" - " + k.type + " Error"); a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + i).find(".uploadifyProgress").hide(); a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + i).addClass("uploadifyError") } }); if (typeof (f.onUpload) == "function") { a(this).bind("uploadifyUpload", f.onUpload) } a(this).bind("uploadifyProgress", { action: f.onProgress, toDisplay: f.displayData }, function (k, i, j, l) { if (k.data.action(k, i, j, l) !== false) { a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + i + "ProgressBar").animate({ width: l.percentage + "%" }, 250, function () { if (l.percentage == 100) { a(this).closest(".uploadifyProgress").fadeOut(250, function () { a(this).remove() }) } }); if (k.data.toDisplay == "percentage") { displayData = " - " + l.percentage + "%" } if (k.data.toDisplay == "speed") { displayData = " - " + l.speed + "KB/s" } if (k.data.toDisplay == null) { displayData = " " } a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + i).find(".percentage").text(displayData) } }); a(this).bind("uploadifyComplete", { action: f.onComplete }, function (l, i, k, j, m) { if (l.data.action(l, i, k, unescape(j), m) !== false) { a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + i).find(".percentage").text(" - Completed"); if (f.removeCompleted) { a("#" + a(l.target).attr("id") + i).fadeOut(250, function () { a(this).remove() }) } a("#" + a(l.target).attr("id") + i).addClass("completed") } }); if (typeof (f.onAllComplete) == "function") { a(this).bind("uploadifyAllComplete", { action: f.onAllComplete }, function (i, j) { if (i.data.action(i, j) !== false) { c = [] } }) }
        })
    }, uploadifySettings: function (f, j, c) { var g = false; a(this).each(function () { if (f == "scriptData" && j != null) { if (c) { var i = j } else { var i = a.extend(a(this).data("settings").scriptData, j) } var l = ""; for (var k in i) { l += "&" + k + "=" + i[k] } j = escape(l.substr(1)) } g = document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id") + "Uploader").updateSettings(f, j) }); if (j == null) { if (f == "scriptData") { var b = unescape(g).split("&"); var e = new Object(); for (var d = 0; d < b.length; d++) { var h = b[d].split("="); e[h[0]] = h[1] } g = e } } return g }, uploadifyUpload: function (b, c) { a(this).each(function () { if (!c) { c = false } document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id") + "Uploader").startFileUpload(b, c) }) }, uploadifyCancel: function (b) { a(this).each(function () { document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id") + "Uploader").cancelFileUpload(b, true, true, false) }) }, uploadifyClearQueue: function () { a(this).each(function () { document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id") + "Uploader").clearFileUploadQueue(false) }) }
    })
})(jQuery)};
```

This method is called on cancel button and delete the file uploaded in directory.

```cs
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public decimal DeleteFileAttachment(string FileNameTOBeDeleted)
{
    try
    {
    string foldername = Convert.ToString(Session["DestinationPath"]);
        FileNameTOBeDeleted = FileNameTOBeDeleted.Replace("- Completed", "");
        FileNameTOBeDeleted = FileNameTOBeDeleted.Replace("\r\n", "");
        string FilePath = foldername + "\\" + FileNameTOBeDeleted;
        FileInfo FName = new FileInfo(FilePath);
        decimal s1 = FName.Length;
        decimal size = s1 / 1000;
        File.Delete(foldername + "\\" + FileNameTOBeDeleted);
        return size;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

`Session["DestinationPath"]` contains path of folder to save the documents uploaded.